# xsl template match using external parameter as variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transform the following xml:

```
<root>
        <row id="1">
            <order>4711</order>
            <customer>a</customer>
        </row>
        <row id="3">
            <order>4712</order>
            <customer>a</customer>
        </row>
        <row id="4">
            <order>4713</order>
            <customer>b</customer>
        </row>
        <row id="5">
            <order>4714</order>
            <customer>c</customer>
        </row>
    </root>
```

...into the xml below, by dynamically filtering on the value of customer using external parameters

```
<root>
    <row id="1">
        <order>4711</order>
        <customer>a</customer>
    </row>
    <row id="3">
        <order>4712</order>
        <customer>a</customer>
    </row>
</root>
```

I managed to construct the following xsl and the result is as expected, if I transfer the param as filterAt=customer and filterVal=a:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="filterVal"/>
    <xsl:param name="filterAt"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$filterAt]=$filterVal">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I am wondering whether I can also make the template-match argument as an external parameter. My current argument of match is "row".  I would like to pass a third parameter called "rowName" and dynamically use it in the match. Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried the following but xmlspy won't even allow it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="filterVal"/>
    <xsl:param name="filterAt"/>
    <xsl:param name="rowName"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="$rowName">
        <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$filterAt]=$filterVal">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"xmlspy won't even allow it"* What does that mean? If there's an error message, quote it verbatim. Note that a template matching a variable will never match anything in the input XML.

Comment: thank you michael @michael-hor257k for your comment. It is just a parse error from xmlspy and the error message is "parameter match is not a valid pattern". You are right, this will not match anything.

Comment: Well, the thing is that what you have IS a valid pattern in XSLT 2.0 and higher. So the message suggests you're using an XSLT 1.0 processor. OTOH, you have accepted an XSLT 3.0 answer, so ...

Comment: Hi Michael @michael-hor257k thanks for your follow-up. Yes since I use Saxon processor it is fine for me to use XSLT 3.0 as well. The match-pattern "$rowName" is indeed not valid. Not only xmlspy throws an error, the saxon processor also have an exception: "XPTY0004: The required item type of the match pattern is node(); the supplied value "row" is an atomic value". I have constructed a working xsl 2.0 solution and posted below

Comment: It's a fine point, but... There is nothing wrong with the match pattern as such. The problem is the data type of the matched variable. That's different from XSLT 1.0, where any reference to a variable in a match pattern is an error, regardless of the variable's data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 and later you can use e.g. `match="*[local-name() = $filterAt and . = $filterVal"` or perhaps even easier with an empty template to not copy the non matching elements e.g. `<xsl:template match="*[local-name() = $filterAt][not(. = $filterVal)]"/>`.

Also in XSLT 3, the current version of XSLT, there are static parameters and shadow attributes (notice the `_match`) e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="row-name" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'row'"/>

<xsl:template _match="{$row-name}">...</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 1.0, template patterns may not use variables. But you can express the condition in an `<xsl:when>` element:

```xml
<xsl:template match="*" priority="1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name()=$rowName">
      <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$filterAt]=$filterVal">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Noteworthy points:

- The template has priority 1 so that it takes precedence over the `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">` when an element node matches both.
- The `<xsl:otherwise>` duplicates the content of the `<xsl:template match="node()|@*">` template.

Comment: *"Template patterns may not use variables."* That's true in XSLT 1.0. OP's stylesheet says `version="2.0"`.

Comment: Thank you. Although it is in 1.0 but it works for me and this is great. @heiko-theißen

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @martin-honnen I am able to construct the solution for xsl 2.0 and 3.0

XSL 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="filterVal"/>
    <xsl:param name="filterAt"/>
    <xsl:param name="rowName"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()=$rowName]">
        <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$filterAt]=$filterVal">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSL 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:param name="filterVal"/>
    <xsl:param name="filterAt"/>
    <xsl:param name="row-name" as="xs:string" static="yes" select="'row'"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template _match="{$row-name}">
        <xsl:if test="*[local-name()=$filterAt]=$filterVal">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```